# Responsive and re-size two div side by side using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page like this snippet code. `LeftCol` is a re-sizable div. with of `LeftCol` and `RightCol` div must set with re-size the browser.

I have two problem :

1. if i scroll `LeftCol` , re-size don't work.
2. when i change width of browser to near **696px** , `RightCol` placed in the bottom of the `LeftCol` :

[image]

Could you help me , please?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            //resize
            $("#LeftCol").resizable({
                maxHeight: 250,
                maxWidth: ($("#parent").width() * 2) / 3,
                minHeight: 150,
                minWidth: 200
            });

            $('#LeftCol').resize(function () {
                $('#RightCol').width($("#parent").width() - $("#LeftCol").width());
            });
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('#RightCol').width($("#parent").width() - $("#LeftCol").width());
                $('#LeftCol').height($("#parent").height());
            });
        });
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #header {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #parent {
            position: fixed;
            top: 110px;
            bottom: 110px;
            /*background-color: #00fffe;*/
            width: 99%;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        #LeftCol {
            height: 100%;
            width: 20%;
            max-width:80%;
            float: left;
            background-color: #C7C5C5;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #RightCol {
            height: 100%;
            background-color:rgb(224, 223, 223) ;
            width: auto;
            overflow: auto;
            direction:ltr;
        }

        .wrapper {
            direction:rtl;
            padding:10px;
        }

        #footer {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<link href="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kaminet.ir/ss/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<section id="content">
            <div id="header">
            </div>

            <div id="parent" class="container">

                <div id="LeftCol">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        start
                        <br>
                        salam salam salam salam salam salam salam salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        end
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="RightCol">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        start
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam

                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        end
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block` to both columns

Comment: @ Druzion , No effect !!

Comment: Add display:block to the parent container, and display:inline to the children columns.

Set the width of the parent to auto.

Set the width of the children to whatever width you need them to be (I recommend using percentages instead of fixed widths.

Add an empty div below the parent container called clear and apply clear:both to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is more big, because the scrollWidth. Try this

**UPDATE**

I have separate the wrapper class and add `overflow:hidden` to leftcol and `overflow:auto` to wrapper in leftcol.

Please try now, is work fine

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            //resize
            $("#LeftCol").resizable({
                maxHeight: 250,
                maxWidth: ($("#parent").width() * 2) / 3,
                minHeight: 150,
                minWidth: 200
            });

            $('#LeftCol').resize(function () {
                $('#RightCol').width($("#parent").width() - $("#LeftCol").width());
            });
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $('#RightCol').width($("#parent").width() - $("#LeftCol").width()-1);
                $('#LeftCol').height($("#parent").height());
            });
        });
```

```css
body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            #header {
                background-color: red;
                height: 100px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #parent {
                position: fixed;
                top: 110px;
                bottom: 110px;
                /*background-color: #00fffe;*/
                width: 99%;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
            }

            #LeftCol {
                height: 100%;
                width: 20%;
                max-width:80%;
                float: left;
                background-color: #C7C5C5;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #RightCol {
                height: 100%;
                background-color:rgb(224, 223, 223) ;
                width: auto;
                overflow: auto;
                direction:ltr;
            }

         #LeftCol  .wrapper {
                direction:rtl;
                padding:10px;
              height:100%;
              overflow:auto;
            }

           #RightCol  .wrapper {
                direction:rtl;
                padding:10px;
            }

            #footer {
                background-color: red;
                height: 100px;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<link href="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kaminet.ir/ss/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://kaminet.ir/ss/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<section id="content">
            <div id="header">
            </div>

            <div id="parent" class="container">

                <div id="LeftCol">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        start
                        <br>
                        salam salam salam salam salam salam salam salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        end
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="RightCol">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        start
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam

                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        salam
                        <br>
                        end
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </section>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r8hhjs37/1/

Comment: thank you so much. the second problem was solved. can you help me with first problem?After Scrolling down LeftCol , this column can't be re-sized?

Comment: what are you trying to do when you scrollDown?